# How to encrypt RDP password in Java

Tags: java, rdp

I want to generate rdp file with auto-login capability, so need to generate encrypted password and fill in the rdp file.

For encryption tool, I am using the Crypt32Util from jna open source (I also tried DPAPI DataProtector, the result is the same). But the result is not correct...

As pointed in http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/ , the string should be in unicode, that's why I use 'UTF-16LE' in getBytes (I also had tried to use getBytes() and getBytes("UTF-8"), no one works...)

Really appreciate your help to throw me some light, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
public String pwdEncrypt(String password){
    byte[] pwdBytes = null;
    try{
        pwdBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] encryptedPwd = Crypt32Util.cryptProtectData(pwdBytes);       

    return String.valueOf(Hex.encodeHex(encryptedPwd));
}
```

Comment: UTF-16 is not the same as Unicdoe.  What happens if you simply use password.getBytes()?  You should be able to compare your encoding with that of the test program on that blog post you have posted.

Comment: Joe, thanks! Actually I had also tried to use getBytes(), but the result does not work either... I am not sure how unicode bytes are organized in C++ or Delphi. I guess the problem is the pwdBytes fed into the crypt API are not correct, but do not know how to compare and fix...

Answer (score 1):

```
   String paasword ="pwd";
    DATA_BLOB pDataIn = new DATA_BLOB(password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16LE")));
    DATA_BLOB pDataEncrypted = new DATA_BLOB();
    System.out.println(Crypt32.INSTANCE.CryptProtectData(pDataIn, "psw", 
            null, null, null, WinCrypt.CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, pDataEncrypted));
   StringBuffer epwsb = new StringBuffer();
   byte[] pwdBytes= new byte [pDataEncrypted.cbData];      
   pwdBytes=pDataEncrypted.getData();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(epwsb);
     for ( final byte b : pwdBytes ) {
    formatter.format("%02X", b);
         }
  System.out.println("password 51:b:"+ epwsb.toString());
```

Comment: that's correct but you should specify that for getting this working you also need include jna and jna-platform (https://github.com/twall/jna)

Comment: What is `DATA_BLOB`? Where have you imported it from?